# PHP PDO class Query method returns true or false when no record found

Tags: php, pdo

As per the PHP document

PDO::query() returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure.

My question here is whether an empty result is considered a failure or success?

Comment: an empty result isn't a failure

Comment: A query that returns no rows, because there are no rows that satify the criteria, is still a valid query and will not return FALSE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An empty result set is still a successful execution of the query.  It will return a PDOStatement object.

Comment: But the PDOStatement Object will have zero records right? Will the fetch() statement on the PDOStatement return false?

Comment: Note, the documentation is only *partially* correct. If you have `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` set (which you should) it will not return `false` if the query failed to execute, but instead it will throw an exception.

Comment: @Devon Will the fetch() statement on the PDOStatement return false?

Comment: @RinsadAhmed yes, fetch returns false when it has no more rows left in the result set.  This is why `while ($row = $stmt->fetch())` works and does not create an endless loop.

Comment: But the document says on failure? Is it a failure?

Comment: Probably not the best documentation of the return value but I  suppose so since it fails to fetch any additional result out of the result set.